# List of Abbreviations title not showing

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a problem with the list of abbreviations. I can see it in the table of contents, but it is not showing the title. I do not see the title when I go to the page.

I have used the following code:

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\chapter{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\textit{To my family}!


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\listofabbrevations
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please post a code that can be compiled?